# Laravel 5.3 multi database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

This maybe common question, but i've been stuck for 2 days T_T

it's pretty simple,

- I create a new laravel 5.3 project
- I remove db config in .env file
- I define 2 x db connections in config/database.php as follow:

  ```
  'connections' => [
      'web' => [
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'host' => 'localhost',
          'port' => '3306',
          'database' => 'db_host1',
          'username' => 'username1,
          'password' =>  'secret1',
          'charset' => 'utf8',
          'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
          'prefix' => '',
          'strict' => true,
          'engine' => null,
      ],
      'another' => [
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'host' => 'localhost',
          'port' => '3306',
          'database' => 'db_host2',
          'username' => 'username2',
          'password' =>  'secret2',
          'charset' => 'utf8',
          'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
          'prefix' => '',
          'strict' => true,
          'engine' => null,
      ],
  ]
  ```

  it's clear and straight forward
- php artisan make auth
- modify migrations as follow:

  ```
  class CreateUsersTable extends Migration{
      //bla....
      public function up(){
            Schema::connection('another')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                  //bla
            }
        //bla
      }

  class CreatePasswordResetsTable extends Migration{
      //bla....
      public function up(){
          Schema::connection('another')->create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
          //bla
      }
      //bla
  }
  ```

  it's clear and straight forward
- php artisan migrate - sweet, db created in a right place
- goto registercontroller.php and modify create method as follow:

  ```
  protected function create(array $data){
    return User::create([
        'connection' => 'another',
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
  }
  ```
- I also tried to put connection in `app/User.php` as follow:

  ```
  class User extends Authenticatable{
      use Notifiable;
      protected $connection = 'another';
  ```
- test to register user - fill up all form fields and submit
- DANG! error comeout:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'web.users'
>   doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where
>   `email` = my@email.com)

question: why it still look up from 'web' DB connection as i have told to use 'another' DB connection T_T ?

am i missed anything here?

i have read a couple doc like: http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

but it doesnt help me...

appreciate if someone could help me here :)

cheers,

Comment: Why is your `protected $connection = 'core'`, when your connection is named `another`?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, it should be 'another' and still not work - i edit the question.

Comment: It's `\DB::connection` not `Schema::connection`. The article you linked is over 3 years old. [Why not reference the docs?](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#using-multiple-database-connections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the validation part. Though you changed the connection to another in the validation part your still looking out for web connection users table just replace the following code in RegisterController and you are good to go.

```
return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:another.users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
```

unique:another.users *This part is important as it tells which connection to be used and the table for the field under validation.

credits: [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/multiple-database?page=1#reply-281717)

Answer (score 0):

The method `Schema::connection()` doesn't actually exist. The ideal way to do this, would be to get the schemabuilder for the connection:

```
DB::connection('another')->getSchemaBuilder()->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // definitions
}
```

There are actually several ways to do this, and I could go into them all, but this is the simplest.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, isn't schema only read when you do "php artisan migrate"? after that, it'll be technically not in use? FYI, my "Schema::connection('another')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table)" is a migration file (database/migration/yyyy_mm_dd_filename.php

Comment: I don't understand your question, or the relevance. The migrations are only read when you run `php artisan migrate`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: My point is: either way i change db:;connection or keep usong schema connection, it doesnt matter because that migration file only used during php artisan migration, and it is actually works. But after the migration done and you try to register user for example, it wont read those migration file anymore.

Comment: @AnD, you're missing the point entirely.

1. The code here doesn't change the connection, it returns the connection object for the name provided, and then grabs a SchemaBuilder for that connection.
2. The `Schema::connection` method _DOES NOT EXIST_. Also, it doesn't work, have you verified that the migrations are creating the tables on the correct database?

Comment: Hi ollieread, yes when I run php artisan migration with schema::connection it creating me the correct table at the correct database